# What does quantization of spin have to do with spinors?

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-spin, representation-theory, dirac-equation, spinors

A fermion has half-integer spin.  In the context of the theory, this means its wavefunction is made of spinors: geometric objects which, under Lorentz rotations, transform in such a way that they require two full revolutions to return to their initial value.  Hence they only "spin by half" under a single full rotation.  (Or you can think of them invariantly as elements of the even spacetime sub-algebra.)

But what does this have to do with the fact that the fermion is always measured as spin up or spin down, with a magnitude of $\frac12\hbar$? (Another reference to "half" that apparently has no connection to the first.)  For example, what would a spin eigenstate look like in terms of spinors?

Answer (score 0):

> A fermion has half-integer spin.  In the context of the theory, this means...

> But what does this have to do with the fact that the fermion is always measured as spin up or spin down...

The irreducible representation for a given spin $s$ is a matrix of size $2s+1$. For a particle with spin $1/2$ this representation consists of 2-by-2 matrices.

This means that (in this representation) an eigenvector of $S_z$ is a 2-by-1 matrix. We call the eigenvector with eigenvalue $1/2$ "spin up" and the eigenvector with eigenvalue -1/2 "spin down."

---

As another example, consider a spin 3/2 particle. This particle is associated with the 4-by-4 size irreducible representation of the rotation group. In this case we would not just have "spin up" and "spin down," but rather four different $S_z$ eigenvectors (with $S_z$ values: -3/2, -1/2, 1/2, and +3/2).

Comment: It seems like you're only talking about the representation of the spin eigenstates, not how they relate to the spinors the wavefunction is made of (and the transformation properties thereof)...

Comment: I'm just trying to answer the question as I understand it. In particular, the part of the question that I quoted in my answer... The spin-1/2 spinors are just complex vectors made up of those two basis states (spin up and spin down). Here's a quote from "A Child’s Guide to Spinors" by William O. Straub (available online via googling): "So what is a spinor? It’s essentially a two-component vector-like quantity in which rotations and Lorentz boosts are built into the overall formalism. "

Comment: Okay that helps (and I didn't mean to be unappreciative) -- so what about Dirac spinors with their 4 components (which is the more unified kind, and the only kind that transforms under the full Lorentz group)?  I've heard it's 4 components because of the antiparticle -- so do the eigenstates somehow specify both charge and spin?  But we don't talk about electric charge as an operator, right?  Isn't the antiparticle the adjoint or something?  Then why are there 4 components?  Can you see my confusion?

Comment: Those four components are basically just a stack of *two* spin-1/2 spinors (each a matrix of size 2-by-1). Basically to get the rotation part of the Lorentz group you take the direct sum of *two* 2-by-2 matrix representations of the rotation group (the spinors). But you have to add some more stuff since the Lorentz group has more than just rotations (it has boosts too). I don't recall the details. The point in that the 4-component Dirac spinor doesn't represent a spin-3/2 particle, but rather it represents two spin-1/2 particles (the electron and positron).

Comment: (Because it is a direct sum, the 4-by-4 representation is by definition reducible, so it can not represent a spin-3/2 particle)